# where clause is ignored when query list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, caml-query

I have a CAML query which returns lists by a lookup field.

here is the query

```
<Query>                    
         <Where>
           <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Ticket' LookupId = 'TRUE' />
                <Value Type='Lookup'>75</Value>
           </Eq>
           </Where> </Query>
```

According to the data in my list this query should not return anything, but it returns all the rows. in a couple of articles, removing Query tag suggested as fix, but it did not fix my issue.

is there any way to find why this query does not work? I am using Client Object Model

Update: Here is the code I use to query items,

```
SP.ListItemCollection noteItems = null;
                List<TicketNote>  notes = new List<TicketNote>();
                using (SP.ClientContext clientContext = GetClientContext())
                {
                    SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Note");
                    SP.CamlQuery camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();


                    camlQuery.ViewXml = @"
                    <Query>                    
                        <Where>
                           <Eq>
                               <FieldRef Name='Ticket' LookupId = 'True' />
                               <Value Type='Lookup'>75</Value>
                            </Eq>
                        </Where></Query>";

                    noteItems = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                    clientContext.Load(noteItems);

                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Are the spaces around = in FieldRef also in your code? That's not valid xml!

Comment: I had the same problem and the &lt;View>&lt;Query>&lt;Where>...&lt;/Where>&lt;/Query>&lt;/View> worked Both &lt;Query>&lt;Where>...&lt;/Where>&lt;/Query> and &lt;Where>...&lt;/Where> failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you need to wrap the QUERY tag into a VIEW. If you have fields which could be NULL it is wise to add `<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><ProjectProperty Name='Title' Nullable='TRUE'/></ViewFields>`

Comment: nope did not really worked..

Comment: wrapping the query with <View> tag sorted.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this one. This is tried and tested..**

```
context.Load(context.Web);
            List oList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("test");
            context.Load(oList);

            string ID = "75";
            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery()
            {
                ViewXml = @"<View>
                            <Query>
                               <Where>
                                  <Eq>
                                    <FieldRef Name='Ticket' LookupId='TRUE'  />
                                     <Value Type='Integer'>" + ID + @"</Value>
                                  </Eq>
                               </Where>
                            </Query></View>"
            };

            Item = oList.GetItems(query);
            context.Load(Item);
            context.ExecuteQueryAsync(sucess, failed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Integer as value type:

```
<Value Type='Integer'>75</Value>
```

Comment: Nope nothing changed...

Comment: updated the code.

Comment: Actually you need to wrap the QUERY tag into a VIEW. If you have fields which could be NULL it is wise to add <View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><ProjectProperty Name='Title' Nullable='TRUE'/></ViewFields>....etc.

Comment: @C.Marius could you update your answer with the comment you made as it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
<Where>            
      <Eq>                 
          <FieldRef Name='Ticket' LookupId = 'TRUE' />
          <Value Type='Lookup'>75</Value>
       </Eq>
</Where>
```

Instead of :

```
<Query>                              
   <Where>            
      <Eq>                 
          <FieldRef Name='Ticket' LookupId = 'TRUE' />
          <Value Type='Lookup'>75</Value>
       </Eq>
   </Where> 
</Query>
```